# How to plot Power Iteration Clustering model using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, apache-spark

So I implemented the Power Iteration Clustering in Spark(inbuilt) with the Dataset I have. I got the model after using this

```
model = PowerIterationClustering.train(similarities, 2, 10)
```

When I do

```
model.assignments.collect()
```

I've all the values.

Now I want to plot a scatter plot of this model using Matplotlib.
But I'm not able to understand how to do it.
I got that x and y in the below code is id and cluster in model-

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
```

But I'm not able to understand how to use it. What should be the area, colors ?

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand what does the collected assignment represent?

Comment: I know that it contains all the id and cluster value...
Assignment(id=3, cluster=0)

Answer (score 1):

You first need to parse the Assignment tuple, then collect. The output will be:

```
(<id int>, <cluster int>)
```

Instead of

```
Assignment(id=..,cluster=...)
```

You can do this by

```
model.assignments.map(lambda asm: (asm[0], asm[1])).collect()
```

You can then extract the x and y from the resulting list of tuples.